# Blocker Bug with Aloha Editor / ExtJS, We Need Your Help

Tags: extjs, aloha-editor

We have a blocker bug with Aloha Editor which is holding back the 0.10 release. I've been at it all day, and cannot figure it out. So I'm opening it up to you guys.

See the error report here:
https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues#issue/75

Thanks. **I will award a 200 reputation bounty to whoever solves this.**

Comment: If you are going to award a bounty, why not assign the question a bounty?

Comment: @Nicholas T - you have to wait 24 hours after the question was posted to assign a bounty. It hasn't been that long yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to initialise the buttons twice.

If you put a breakpoint on `floatingmenu.js#436` when `scopeObject.buttons.length > 6` you can see it trying to add a second bold button to the buttonGroup. It succeeds; I can only assume it's not supposed to.

The ids of the two bold buttons are suspiciously similar.

I haven't tracked down just why it's initialising them twice, but hopefully that's a start.

Comment: Thanks mate :) Yeah the thing that got me was that after a particular amount of time it would die. I then went to the initialise code, and turns out one of our merges added code to initialise aloha editor twice: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/19a7d12648024ec5312b3dd8f007e8c6d6cd774b/src/core/core.js#L811 - argh. You can see the fix here: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/commit/7a7f98a40f6f03c20c660855851ac68ddad7aa1d

Comment: Hey wombleton. Had to wait a while to open the bounty. Just opened it. Have to wait 24 hours to award it. Sorry about the long wait.

Comment: There you go :) Thanks again!